# WAPP Portable - 64 bit

Tags: database, postgresql, 64-bit, portability

I downloaded WAPP portable from http://portableapps.com/node/23022 but am trying to increase the shared_buffer beyond 1GB which I believe is failing because the stack includes a 32 bit postgresql. I cannot seem to find any stack with postgresql 64 bit.

Does any stack include postgresql 64 bit?

There are stacks like http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/ with 64 bit mysql so I do not understand why the same are not apparently available for postgresql.

If not is there any easy way -- or a useful guide anyone has written -- to make a raw install of postgresql 64 bit transferrable from one computer to another (ie. simply copying and pasting the directory over to another computer, say C:\postgresql\ on computer A then copying to the same path on computer B, and then executing a script to start/shut down, with nothing else to do)? Is this even possible?

edit -- in response to Craig -

I don't have much knowledge of postgresql or how the cache works. I'll clarify a few things. First, yes, I'm using Windows.

I'm using the database to analyze a very large data set (couple hundred million rows) and just want to make sure it is fully taking advantage of the ram available on my machine so as to reduce the amount that has to be read from the disk. In mysql simply increasing the innodb buffer pool results in a very noticeable performance gain and its use of ram is easily verifiable simply by going to the task manager (as, upon running any intensive query, it quickly increases to the amount its been set to).

Are you saying that with postgresql I won't see the memory use of any of its processes accurately reflect the amount of ram the database is using? If so how do I tell how much ram it is using?

As for it being portable, I really only care about the ability to copy the folder and then be able to use that folder -- representing the database as of a moment in time -- later on (for backup purposes). I don't care so much about actually being able to run it from a usb drive. The machine I have the database on has an SSD. I just want to make copies of the folder, stash them somewhere, and then be able to re-use them if I need to. Does that affect how I should go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily *need* to increase `shared_buffers` over 1GB; it's not clear why you're doing this. PostgreSQL uses all the system's memory as cache, though that memory will appear as "free" in the operating system it's really used for disk cache. For the sorts of uses I'd expect for a portable apps build I'd be surprised if you really needed to increase `shared_buffers`.

That said, yes, it's pretty easy to take PostgreSQL and make it "portable". Assuming you're on Windows (since you didn't say, and the portable apps thing is mostly a Windows thing) you can [download the "binaries only" zip](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) and unpack it on your removable storage medium. Use `initdb` to create a new database cluster on the removable storage. Then write some quick batch scripts that `pg_ctl start` and `pg_ctl stop` the server.

Caveats:

- All computers must run the same architecture's PostgreSQL build. You can't run 32-bit PostgreSQL on 32-bit systems, 64-bit on 64-bit systems. It's quite OK to run 32-bit PostgreSQL on both 32- and 64-bit Windows, and that'll work fine, which is probably why there's no portable apps packaged 64-bit PostgreSQL.
- The storage must not be formatted FAT32. NTFS is required for Windows.
- While it's not absolutely necessary, it's a good idea to stop the server before removing the storage. If the storage doesn't honour flush requests (some USB keys and SD cards) then it's absolutely vital otherwise data corruption will result. `pg_test_fsync` can help - if flush rates reported are way higher than makes sense for the storage, be suspicious.
- Removable storage is often very slow. This will be reflected in PostgreSQL's performance. Use eSATA or FireWire 800 if possible. USB3 as a second choice. Anything else will be horrid and you will *need* to have enough RAM to cache the whole dataset to get decent performance. (This doesn't have to be `shared_buffers`, just enough free system RAM).

Comment: Craig, thanks, see my edit for clarification. Couldn't add it here because of the character limit.

Comment: Ugh, that's a totally different question. Re memory use: Unlike MySQL, PostgreSQL relies on the *operating system* for disk cache. So it *does not* show disk cache as RAM used by PostgreSQL. You don't need to increase `shared_buffers` for cache, and it can be counterproductive.  As for portability: The manual is your friend. What you want in this case is to just *stop the database server* and *copy the data directory* - or to use `pg_basebackup` if you want a live copy. Very simple. See the manual. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Comment: Thanks, just as a follow-up then, w/ 16gb of ram as in my case, the database won't be able to use any less w/ a 32 bit install than a 64 bit install will it? Because it's use the OS cache which is a 64 bit (in my case)? Also is there any way to tell within postgresql how much of the OS cache it's using?

Comment: DB won't be able to use any more/less *as disk cache*. There is certainly a limit where more shared_buffers will be beneficial, but I really doubt it matters tons for your workload. Yes, because it relies on the OS for caching. No, there's no way within Pg to tell how much disk data the OS is caching, because the OS is caching it not PostgreSQL.